# How to stop DAG from backfilling? catchup_by_default=False and catchup=False does not seem to work and Airflow Scheduler from backfilling

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

The setting catchup_by_default=False in airflow.cfg does not seem to work.  Also adding catchup=False to the DAG doesn't work neither.

Here's how to reproduce the issue.  I always start from a clean slate by running `airflow resetdb`.  As soon as I unpause the dag, the tasks start to backfill.

Here's the setup for the dag.  I'm just using the [tutorial example](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/dags/tuto.py).

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2018, 9, 16),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG("tutorial", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1), catchup=False)
```

Comment: Did you run `airflow initdb` again after setting `catchup_by_default=False` in `airflow.cfg`?

Comment: Pretty sure I wiped out everything, including removing the docker volume, and re-initdb every time.  It still didn't work.  That's why it's baffling.  I also tried both Sequential and Local Executer, even though I doubt it would make any difference.

Comment: @kaxil As soon as I unpause a DAG, it's getting back filled right away even though catchup = False for the Dag and catchup_by_default = False.

Comment: That is odd. What version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: I'm running version 1.10.0.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm seeing the same issue as @Sam with v1.10.0

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is a little old. But, setting `catch_up_default = False` in `airflow.cfg` did stop `airflow` from backfilling for me.
(My `Airflow` version is 1.10.12)

I resent that this config is not set to `False` by default. This and the fact that the dag starts one `schedule_interval` after the `start_date` are the two most confusing things that stumps Airflow beginners.

The first time I used `Airflow`,  I wasted one entire afternoon, trying to figure out why my test task which was scheduled to run every 5 mins was running at quick succession (say every 5-6 seconds). It took me a while to realize that it was `backfill` in action.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear if you enabled this DAG that you specified when the time now is 2018-10-22T9:00:00.000EDT (which is what, 2018-10-22T13:00:00.000Z) it would be would be started some time after 2018-10-22T13:00:00.000Z with a run date marked 2018-10-21T00:00:00.000Z.

This is not back filling from the start date, but without any prior run, it does "catchup" the most recent completed valid period; I'm not sure why that's been the case in Airflow for a while, but it's [documented](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=backfill#backfill-and-catchup) that `catchup=False` means create a single run of the very most recent valid period.

If the dagrun run date is further confusing to you, please recall that run dates are the `execution_date` which is the start of the interval period. The data for the interval is only completely available at the end of the interval period, but Airflow is designed to pass in the start of the period.

Then the next run would *start* sometime after 2018-10-23T00:00:00.000Z with an `execution_date` set as 2018-10-22T00:00:00.000Z.

If, on the 22nd or later, you're getting any run date earlier than the 21st, or multiple runs scheduled, then yes `catchup=False` is not working. But there's no other reports of that being the case in v1.10 or v1-10-stable branch.

Comment: I get your point and I understand how it helps with ETL processes that are completely written in Airflow. My problem is how do we use Airflow as a pure scheduler which runs jobs only when that schedule has come up. For example, if we have a job that runs at 8AM-UTC, if the DAG is turned OFF at that time and and turned ON at 8:15AM-UTC it shouldn't run. Currently even with `LatestOnlyOperator` what I have noticed is it runs jobs if it is within the `start_date + some_schedule_period`. Is there a way to get past this issue/Airflow_feature?

Comment: @SuhasHegde That `catchup=false` behavior of running the single most recent period only happens with a new dag that has no prior runs, if you turn off the dag after it ran once, and turn it back on later, it won't be catching up an 8-8am run at 8:15, because it missed it.
It is a bad 'pure scheduler'; cron is better for that.
You could write cron or jenkins jobs that trigger dag runs through the cli or the web api, I'm not sure whether it will run a turned off dag, I don't think so. With an external scheduled trigger, you should set the `schedule_interval=None`.

Comment: For me, let's just say I have a DAG with start date of 1/1/2018 and schedule to run @daily.  Now this is the first time I start airflow with a new database.  No DAG has ever run before.  As soon as I unpause my DAG, the scheduler will start running the DAG starting on 1/1/2018, 1/2/2018, 1/3/2018, so on and so forth up until now.  I thought the catchup=False is to stop this behavior from happening.  Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: @Sam Your understanding is right and this behavior appears to be some kind of bug you've hit. Could you look into the https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/AIRFLOW/issues to file details about the problem? Also you could try to bring this up on apache-airflow.slack.com which is has some kind of invite flow https://apache-airflow-slack.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @dlamblin, We are currently using Cron and trying to move a legacy system to Airflow. We still need everything to run only according to its Cron-schedule but have the benefit of UI-access, being able to run jobs on multiple clusters such as on cloud etc.. That is why this question is relevant to me. Should have mentioned that earlier I guess.

Comment: @SuhasHegde I do like Airflow; but for only replacing a scheduler with a web UI I also like Jenkins, and if your jobs are Hadoop based, Hue has Oozie with scheduling options. Lastly Zeppelin is able to setup interactive notebooks (Jupyter like, but for interpreters like Spark, Presto, Hive etc) which can be scheduled to refresh… not too great for many users but okay for a small team or an individual.

Comment: Thanks @dlamblin for your comments: *If, on the 22nd or later, you're getting any run date earlier than the 21st, or multiple runs scheduled, then yes catchup=False is not working.* :- but from my test it schedules recent two runs (instead just one, the most latest one). I posted the code / screenshots here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260404/catchup-false-why-still-two-schedule-runs-are-scheduled

Comment: @VibhorJain Yes I have fixed that in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8776 and would release this in Airflow 1.10.11

Answer (score 2):

Like @dlamblin mentioned and as mentioned in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html?highlight=backfill#backfill-and-catchup) too Airflow would create a single DagRun for the most recent valid interval. `catchup=False` will instruct the scheduler to only create a DAG Run for the most current instance of the DAG interval series.

Although there was a [BUG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1156) when using a `timedelta` for `schedule_interval` instead of a CRON expression or CRON preset. This has been fixed in Airflow Master with https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8776. We will release Airflow 1.10.11 with this fix.