# Unexpected Dag schedules for catchup=false

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm learning basics of Airflow (apache-airflow==1.10.1, MacBook OSX) and unable to understand the actual schedules created for dag runs.

Created a simple DAG with single PythonOperator:

- some `start_date` in the past
- `schedule_interval`: schedule every 10 minutes
- `catchup` is False because I **DO NOT** want to to any backfill

The system results in following dag runs (execution_date, /start_date)

1. (2019-01-14 01:57:10.404054, 2019-01-14 02:17:10.410499)
2. (2019-01-14 02:07:10.404054, 2019-01-14 02:17:12.226403)
3. (2019-01-14 02:17:10.404054,2019-01-14 02:27:11.797695)

**Considering, I activated the schedule around `2019-01-14T02:17:10`(that’s today UTC 14th Jan19 @2:17:10am), I had expected system to only created schedule in line # 2. & 3, but not the one in line # 1.?**

Here's code:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'ga_mp', 'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 1, 10, 4, 20, 00),
}
dag = DAG(dag_id = 'my_dag_v1',
          default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10),
          catchup=False
       )
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have explained this in detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740904/5691525

There was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1156) that created extra DagRun which is fixed in Airflow Master and would be available in Airflow 1.10.11

Answer (score 0):

I believe a newly created airflow dag following a schedule will automatically run when it is created. Did you initially create the dag at 1:57? That may explain the line 1 run.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I created DAG (`.py` file) long time back, but only moved the file to `$AIFLOW_HOME/dag` folder & switched ON the toggle in webserver UI **@2:17**. That's why I expected the first execution_time would be **2:07** (10 min. prior to start_date as per schedule_interval settings)